# Quasar Vue Framework: Reset validated input field

Tags: vue.js, quasar

The Quasar app I am working on allows to take a picture and to add some text in a input field. After successfully sending the image, dialog appears and offers 2 buttons, one "Take another piture" (and the other redirects to another page):

```
// text input field
<div class="row justify-center q-ma-md">
  <q-input
    v-model="post.caption"
    ref="inputCaption"
    hint="Please enter at least 4 characters."
    :rules="[required(), minLength()]"
    clearable
    label="Caption *"
    dense
    class="col col-sm-6" />
</div>

// Dialog buttons
<q-dialog v-model="savedSuccessfully">
    [...]
    <q-card-actions align="right" class="text-primary">
      <q-btn unelevated rounded color="secondary" label="Take another photo" @click="resetCanvas" />
      <q-btn unelevated rounded color="primary" label="Go to postings" @click="goToPostings" />
    </q-card-actions>
```

The "resetCanvas" function not only resets the image canvas, but also the input field Unfortunately upon `resetValidation()` – which, according to Quasar's documentation should do the job – the input field is still recognised as dirty:

```
resetCanvas() {
  [...]

  this.$refs.inputCaption.resetValidation()
  this.$refs.inputCaption.isDirty = false
},
```

I even added a `this.$refs.inputCaption.isDirty = false` to the reset script, but to no avail. (See screenshot)

[image: Input field still reacts to validation rules after resetValidation()]

What do I have to do to clear the input field properly upon reset?

Comment: there is no resetValidation method in q-input https://quasar.dev/vue-components/input#qinput-api. But q-form has this method https://quasar.dev/vue-components/form#qform-api

Answer (score 1):

For my side I was using Vue 3 and quasar, This is a way I used to reset form after submit:

In template use:

```html
<q-form ref="myForm">
  <!-- Your input field -->
</q-form>
```

In your script tag:

```js
<script>
import {defineComponent, ref} from "vue"

export default defineComponent({
  setup(){
   const myForm = ref(null)
   
   const onSubmit = () => {
    //Your code....
    myForm.value.reset()
   }
   return{
    myForm,
    onSubmit
   }
  }
})
</script>
```

Comment: This hasn't worked for me, but I appreciate the answer. I learned something tangential

Comment: The response code currently works perfect: "quasar": "^2.6.0"

Answer (score 0):

The only thing that worked for me was using @blur on the field and resetting to the original data.

Comment: Can you elaborate?

Comment: Sorry -- When there was an @blur trigger, that would start a function that would reset the field to its original value, e.g., null

Answer (score 0):

[According to documentation](https://quasar.dev/vue-components/form#submitting-to-a-url-native-form-submit-) to validate quasar form on button click in a separate function you should:

1. In the component that you are validating set `lazy-rules='ondemand'` so it waits for validation function to fire and `ref="myForm"` so that validation function knows what form you are validating
2. Attach `@submit="validate"` event handler to you form
3. Create a validation function

```js
setup () {
  const myForm = ref(null)

  function validate () {
    myForm.value.validate().then(success => {
      if (success) {
        // yay, models are correct
      }
      else {
        // oh no, user has filled in
        // at least one invalid value
      }
    })
  }

  // to reset validations:
  function reset () {
    myForm.value.resetValidation()
  }

  return {
    myForm,
    // ...
  }
}
```